# Cats nested Xor catchOnly leftMap

Tags: scala, scala-cats

I have an underlying java api that has methods which can throw a custom exception which can have business meaning or can return different result types (by dynamic class instantiation). Where the method returns a result I have an `A Xor B` where A is an error type, but I wanted to use `Xor.catchOnly[CustomException]` with a leftMap method to convert the exception into an A.

```
import cats.data.Xor
import scala.reflect.ClassTag

def zor[E >: Null <: Throwable : ClassTag, A , B](f: A Xor B)(g: E => A) : A Xor B = {
  Xor.catchOnly[E]{f}.leftMap(g).flatMap(identity)
}

object CustomExceptions {
   class XYZException extends RuntimeException()
   class FooException extends XYZException
   class BarException extends XYZException

   def exceptionToError[E <: XYZException] = (e: E) => {
    e.toString
  }

}

object Xorish {
  import CustomExceptions._
  type OUT = String Xor Int

  def xorCatchOnlyString(f: =>  String Xor Int): String Xor Int =
    Xor.catchOnly[XYZException](f).leftMap(exceptionToError).flatMap(identity)

  def doIt(i: Int): OUT = zor{
    if (i < 0) throw new FooException() 
    else if (i < 10) throw new BarException()
    else if (i < 20) Xor.left("Splat")
    else Xor.right(i)
  } (exceptionToError)

  def doItSoItWorks(i: Int): OUT = xorCatchOnlyString{
    if (i < 0) throw new FooException() 
    else if (i < 10) throw new BarException()
    else if (i < 20) Xor.left("Splat")
    else Xor.right(i)
  }

}
```

I can do this with the `xorCatchOnlyString` call but I was trying to generalise and came up with `zor` but this throws the exception rather than capturing it as I had hoped. Is there some way of doing what what I want as per `zor` ?

Comment: You should probably define the `f` parameter in `zor` as `f: => A Xor B`.

Comment: Oh yes, I should have - but still throws the error when I do

Comment: but works if add type params to zor as per answer below. (flatten not available in version of cats I am using)

Comment: Strange that `Xor.flatten` doesn't work, which version are you using ? `Xor` doesn't have the `flatten` method itself, but gets it from `FlatMap[Xor]`, so it should work with the `cats.implicits._` import.

Comment: 0.5.0, tried various imports but no luck so far

Comment: aha needs:  import cats.syntax.flatMap._

Comment: no still doesn't work as types are't congruent  but flatMap(identity) does!

Comment: You don't need `cats.syntax.flatMap._` if you are using `cats.implicits._`. Are you using an implicit conversion (or what do you mean with *the types aren't congruent*) ?

Comment: Even with implicit I get : `flatten is not a member of cats.data.Xor[A,cats.data.Xor[A,B]]` thought if I made `g: E => A Xor B` it might work but still no.

Comment: `leftMap(g)` just wants a function `A => E` to go from `Xor[A, B]` to `Xor[E, B]` (so you don't return a `Xor[A, B]` in `g`). Without your imports and exact code it's difficult to help you. Can you get my example below as is to compile ? Maybe you could create a new question about why `flatten` doesn't work in your case ?

Comment: I get same error with your code, have tried latest cats as well. Thanks for your time and help. Could be something about my environment I suppose. Will try cats gitter channel as well

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With parameter `f` as a call by need parameter :

```
import cats.data.Xor, cats.implicits._

def zor[E >: Null <: Throwable : ClassTag, A , B](f: => A Xor B)(g: E => A) : A Xor B =
  Xor.catchOnly[E]{f}.leftMap(g).flatten

class XYZException extends RuntimeException()

def f: String Xor Int = throw new RuntimeException("boom")
def g: String Xor Int = throw new XYZException

zor[RuntimeException, String, Int](f)(_.getMessage)
// Xor[String,Int] = Left(boom)

zor[XYZException, String, Int](g)(_ => "xyz")
// Xor[String,Int] = Left(xyz)
```